# How to backup Windows 6.5 /HTC HD2/ data and transfer it to Android 4.2 /Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-s-4, data-transfer, htc-hd2

I have a HTC HD2 / Windows 6.5 / several years. A week ago I got a Samsung Galaxy S4 / Android 4.2 /. My question is what program I could make a backup of the old phone, so I can restore them to the new. Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: What data is it that you want to move across? Are you just talking your address book, or messages, or something more?

Comment: Well mostly address book and messages and events eventually. Anyway, one of the applications will not work on the other.

Answer (score 1):

### HOW TO TRANSFER/BACKUP DATA FROM WINDOWS MOBILE TO ANDROID

To make backups and transfer that data to your Android device, you'll need to install *PIM Backup* on your Windows Mobile device.
Go to [www.dotfred.net](http://www.dotfred.net) and download the *PIM Backup* CAB file for Windows Mobile 6.5 (direct link: http://www.tinyurl.com/PIMBackup65).
Move it to your HTC HD2 and install it.

### Contacts:

1. Make a backup of your contacts with *PIM Backup* and save it as a CSV file.
2. Copy the file to your computer and go to [Google Contacts](http://www.google.com/contacts/). Click on More -> Import.
3. Choose the CSV file and press Import. Once your new phone has a proper connection to the internet, it'll automatically synchronise with the Google servers and you'll see a complete list of your contacts in the Contacts app.

### Calendar/Appointments:

1. Use *PIM Backup* to backup all of your appointments to a CSV file. Copy that CSV file to your computer.
2. Go to [Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/calendar) and click the mechanical wheel and click Settings.
3. Go to Calendars and click Import calendar.
4. Choose the CSV file and press Import. Once your new phone has a proper connection to the internet, it'll automatically synchronise with the Google servers and you'll see your appointments in your Google Calendar app.

### Text Messages/SMS:

1. Use *PIM Backup* to backup your text messages to an `.xml` file. Transfer that file to your phone to `/sdcard/SMSBackupRestore`.
2. Install the free app [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) on your Android device.
   Start it and restore the XML file.

### Call Log:

1. Use *PIM Backup* to backup your call log to an `.xml` file. Transfer that file to your phone to `/sdcard/CallLogBackupRestore`.
2. Install the free app [Call Logs Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.CallLogBackupRestore) on your Android device.
   Start it and restore the XML file.

Comment: This work only for contacts. But Calendar / Apointments; Text Messages / SMS; call logs not working. Any other ideas for dealing with the problem, please.

Comment: I edited my answer. Make sure you move the XML files to `/sdcard/SMSBackupRestore` and `/sdcard/CallLogBackupRestore` . Could you tell me on what point you fail to accomplish the tasks?

Comment: I copy the files in the Documents folder in root. And then ask the program to search for them in it. Detect them, but then can't read the data from them.

Comment: Come on, people. Has anybody had a similar problem. Helpppp meee.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to sync with cloud/online service. My contacts list is confidential not to be uploaded on Google account.

I use dual boot on HD2 and for having the same calendar and contacts on Android HD2, I found MyPhoneExplorer. It will sync your Outlook with your Android device. It is possible to require phone Android drivers.
The Contacts were synced with photo and everything.
Be patient, MyphoneExplorer is not so quick as Activesync.

Answer (score -1):

If you are also a Outlook user and used activesync to sync your old Windows Phone, then a very nice tool to use is Local Sync.
I migrated my contacts, appointments and other data flawlessly from my windows phone to android.

But not SMS data, because that's not data what Outlook handles. But pimbackup should be fine for that.